# WA% in top command

Tags: linux, performance, top

Can someone explain what does the WA% command mean? I've gone thru several SO questions but my doubt still remains

WA is the amount of CPU time that was waiting on IO

How does CPU ever wait on an IO? When a particular process performs an IO, won't the scheduler schedule something else on that CPU

I'm afraid many of the SO questions don't answer that specific doubt of mine – How does CPU ever wait on an IO

A simple example would be great. e.g. for a top with refresh interval of 5s

```
%Cpu(s):  6.5 us,  1.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 61.5 id,  30.0 wa,  0.1 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st

0.325s was spent in us
0.08   was spent in sy
3.075s was spent idle
1.5s   was spent waiting for IO ??? how
0.2s   was spent in the remaining hi & si whatever that is
```

should add to ~5s

can someone explain how exactly the CPU was behaving for the 1.5s in WA? It could not handle any other process so for 1.5s the CPU was not doing anything even if there were processes ready to run? That's the only thing that can distinguish WA fro Idle. If a CPU is idle for 1.5s it most likely means there were no processes to run

Comment: "while it could just do something else" - such as? It needs to work with data. If that data isn't in the CPU L1 cache, it needs to fetch it from the L2 cache. If not in the L2 cache, it needs to fetch from the L3 (if it has one). If it isn't at all on the on die caches, it needs to access main memory. If not in main memory... in needs to access the HDD. [source](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/296709/why-do-we-have-to-wait-for-i-o)

Comment: [io - Can anyone explain precisely what IOWait is? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/12679/can-anyone-explain-precisely-what-iowait-is)